# StandardJS not recognising array.push() as reassignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, lint, standardjs

I've declared an empty array before a loop that then gets populated as the loop runs. My code works fine but when I lint using StandardJS it tells me that the array is never reassigned and should be declared as a const. If i did this then I wouldn't be able to add values to my array and my code wouldn't work. This also means i cant use **standard --fix** because it breaks my code.

```
let primeFactors = []
while (number > 1) {
  if (isPrime(divisor)) {
    if (number % divisor === 0) {
      primeFactors.push(divisor)
      number = number / divisor
    } else {
      divisor++
    }
  } else {
    divisor++
  }
}
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and *should* use `const`.

The name `const` is a bit of a misnomer - it is merely saying that the variable, once declared, cannot be redeclared or reassigned - that is, it always points at the same object in memory (or more generally, is always the same value as when it was first created) For further explanation, see [this post on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Note however that the object can be mutable, even if it's declared as const. Just because `primeFactors` is always pointing at the same array doesn't mean that array can't grow/shrink/change.

In my javascript, very few of my variables are `let` - I use `const` pretty much everywhere, which makes code much easier to read and reason about. (The only times I use `let` is the occasional for each loops, and occasional helper algorithmic methods)

So the linter is technically right, and encouraging best practice - For example, the linter is protecting you from code such as the following - which would cause eg an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`:

```
let primeFactors = []
while (number > 1) {
  if (isPrime(divisor)) {
    if (number % divisor === 0) {
      primeFactors.push(divisor)
      number = number / divisor
    } else {
      divisor++
      primeFactors = null // There's no reason to do this, but it's theoretically possible!
    }
  } else {
    divisor++
  }
}
```